# If $A$ closed and $B$ compact then $A+B$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $x_n\in A+B$ this means $x_n=a_n+b_n$ for some $a_n \in A$ and $b_n \in B$.

Further, suppose that $x_n \to x \in \mathbb{R}$. We want to show that $x\in A+B$.

Because we know that $B$ is compact i.e. bounded and closed we can use the property of boundedness to extract a subsequence $b_{n_k} \to b$ where $b \in B$ by closedness of $B$.

Take any subsequence of $x_n$ say $x_{n_k}$ and let $a_{n_k}=x_{n_k}-b_{n_k}$ because $x_n$ converges to $x$ and $b_{n_k}$ converges to $b$ then $a_{n_k}$ a subsequence of $a_n$ must converge to $x-b$ and because $A$ is closed then $x-b\in A$.

Then it follows that $x=(x-b)+b \in A+B$ because we know $(x-b) \in A$ and $b \in B$.

I'm a little unsure of this proof because I'm not sure if I can say because $a_{n_k}$ converges to $x-b$  $a_n$ converges to $x-b$. Thanks for help in advance.

**EDIT:** Just to mention I've checked the other posts of this same question, but their proof wasn't very clear to me so I rewrote one. Sorry.

Comment: $a_n$ does not need to converge to $x-b$.  As long as $b_{n_k}$ converges to $b$, $a_{n_k} = x_{n_k} - b_{n_k}$ converges to $x - b$, and this is in $A$ because $A$ is closed.

Comment: Your proof seems ok( $a_n$ doesn't need to converge, but $a_{n_k}$ does and this is the only thing you are using) In fact this probe is the standard one. Also, your proof works in fact for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @Don Thousand, that's not true. $A=\{n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and $B=\{-n-\frac{1}{2n}:n \in\mathbb{N}\}$ are closed sets but $A+B$ is not closed since $0$ is an accumulation point of $A+B$ that is not in $A+B$.